# Batch: Delete command only for the specified file

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file that will delete a certain file from a certain (server) path. The following code will delete 123.pdf but if I do not mention the file name specifically it asks me if I want to delete all contents of the folder.

The paths and file names are auto inserted by another script and sometimes the result will be null, that means that no file name will be inserted. 
I will set it to not prompt for yes/no permission and this is dangerous because if no file name is given it will delete the whole folders content.

I only want it to delete only that one exact named file and when/if the command line contains only the path, without the file name - skip and do not delete anything.

**Exemple:**

```
del "\\tbiscan\SCAN\Dosare de executare scanate\Curtea de Apel Bacau\BACAU\280555A\123.pdf"
```

Please help

Comment: How about you show us all the code involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```dos
2>nul ( <"%targetFile%" break ) && del "%targetFile%"
```

Asumming the `%targetFile%` variable contains the reference to the file (or to a folder) to delete this code:

- Tries to open the file for reading using a input redirection operator (the `break` command will do nothing with the file, but we need a command that does not raise an errorlevel but it is not necessary to use `break`, something as `call;` or `type nul` can be used).

  - If the file can be opened there will be not any error and the conditional operator `&&` (execute next command if the previous did not fail) will execute the `del` command.
  - If the file can not be opened (not readable, it is a folder, it does not exist), the redirection can not be executed and an error is generated (hidden by the `2>nul`) and the command after the `&&` conditional operator is not executed.

Comment: I gues this could work (I will test it in the following minutes) but won't that slow down the process alot ?

Comment: @MisterA, It should not. If present the file is not readed, only opened for reading and closed again.